# Group and sort Backendless data in UITableview with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, sorting, sections

I'm looking to group and sort a list of users from backendless, similar to iPhone contacts. I want to add `sectionIndexTitlesForTableView(_:)`, `titleForHeaderInSection(_:)`, and `sectionForSectionIndexTitle(_:)`. I haven't found a tutorial on how to do this, and I have been stuck for weeks.

[image: Alphabetical index]

So far, I'm able to retrieve users and populate the table view. I also implemented `UISearchBarDelegate`.

```
var users: [BackendlessUser] = []
var filteredUsers : [BackendlessUser] = []

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if tableView == self.tableView {

        return users.count

    } else {

        return self.filteredUsers.count
    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = UITableViewCell()

    if tableView == self.tableView {

        let user = users[indexPath.row]

    cell.textLabel?.text = user.name

    } else {

        let filteredUser = filteredUsers[indexPath.row]

        cell.textLabel?.text = filteredUser.name

    }

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must have a dictionary of array (name 'data' for example)

```
data["A"] = ["Ananas", "Anaconda", "Apple"]

data["B"] = ["Banana", "Baby"]

...
data["Z"] = ["Zoro"]
```

begin:

```
let letters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
var headers: [String] = []
var data : [String: [String]] = [:]  // Choose your type

override func viewDidLoad(){
  // Do your stuff...

  headers = letters.keys.sort()

  // init your data var
  data = ...

  tableView.reloadData()
}
```

- for header:

  ```
  override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return headers.count
  }

  func sectionHeaderTitlesForTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> [String]?{

    return headers
  }

  func tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String?{

    return headers[section];
  }
  ```
- cell

  ```
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowInSection section: Int) -> Int {
     // Exemple
     return data[section].count

  }
  ```

Comment: dont forget to put this subject to resolved if it works